# Should the layout of Android's "secure keyboard" be localized?

Tags: security, keyboard, android-12, oppo-coloros, oppo

Some application use the "secure keyboard" of my ColorOS 12.1 (Android 12 customized by Oppo).
While my device is configured to use German language, the keyboard displayed in such apps uses the English QWERTY layout, and even worse:
I'm not offered any diacritical characters when long-pressing a key.
That makes it rather useless for German.

So I wonder: *Is this a security feature, or is it a bug?*

Comment: By "*Some application use the "secure keyboard" of my ColorOS 12.1*", did you mean ColorOS has their own "secure keyboard", not the app's own keyboard implementation? Because AFAIK, Android doesn't have such feature called "secure keyboard".

Comment: Maybe the phrase is incorrect: Is it "incognito keyboard" instead, maybe? Threema has such a setting, too. However there I don't see that effect there (Threema). Where I see it is in the German "WarnWetter" app when I want to add a location via keyboard. There I also noticed that I cannot make a screenshot as it "contains private data" (says Android).

Answer (score 1):

In ColorOS 13 and Threema 5.05 this is no longer an issue; maybe it was a software bug (if it wasn't just bad design).